# String manipulation with whitespaces

Tags: arrays, c, string

I have to input a string and to get from it the course Id and the course name.

my code for this is:

```
char word[200];
    int id=0;
    char *ptrWord;
    scanf("%[^\n]", word);
    printf("%s\n", word);
    id = strtol(word, &ptrWord, 10);
```

these are examples of a valid input.

```
89110 Computer Science 101
89210 Advanced Programming 1
 89111   OOP 101
```

My question is, how to get rid of the spaces after the id ?
for example, the course name of the last input is OOP 101, but using this method i get the whitespaces before the name, and i don't want them.

Comment: Use `fgets` to read one line of input and then use `strtok` to break the string up into the two parts.

Comment: Get the whole line. Find the first and the last space. The string before the first space is the first number. The string after the last is the second number. The string in between is the name. "Strip" spaces as needed from the middle string.

Answer (score 0):

If your format string contains a whitespace character, `scanf` will discard whitespace in the input stream at that position. So use the following code:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", word);
```

You can use it only if you are sure your input file is formatted correctly.

This code will fail if the field is empty - then `scanf` will get confused and discard the newline character `\n` while trying to discard all whitespace - you cannot tell it to discard only normal spaces.